# Large (80gb) dataset, Pandas, and xgboost

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, xgboost

I'm quite comfortable using XGBoost to come up with predictive models; my concern is using it with a dataset that is (to me, at least) massive. I have 4 ~20gb CSV files with some training data that I am trying to clean up and get ready for model training. I am a little confused on how to start getting the data 'primed' for everything else; a few thoughts that I had (and I'm not certain if they are the best) and some limitations I foresee:

- `pymysql` or `sqlalchemy`: take data, somehow pass it in to a SQL database. **QUESTION:** Do I process data first, or process it once it is in the database?
- `Dask` on a single computer (and not a cluster); again, just not sure how to interface it with XGBoost after one-hot encoding.
- Using `Numpy` somehow; I remember reading about how that would work with representing arrays of each column somehow but I can't be damned to remember.
- HDF5 file format; still don't think it would make it small enough to work with reasonably.

My system has 24 GB of RAM on 64-bit Ubuntu. Is there any way to use swap memory somehow to do all of the processing? It would be stupidly slow, certainly.

Effectively I'm wondering what one would recommend for cleaning, one-hot encoding, and training a machine learning algorithm with such a massive data set. Thank you!

Comment: I used pandas hdf5 to store data for neural network, then you can read x amount of rows in at a time to do operations on it

Comment: 80GB is the size of your extracted features or just the raw data? Because if it is the latter, I guess your final feature dataset will be way smaller.

Comment: I suggest converting everything to parquet using dask so you can cherry pick columns for data exploration and future feature engineering.